# Как исправить кодировку письма php

Tags: php, кодировка, email

Есть такая вот функция для отправки сообщений:

```
public function send_email($email, $mess)
{
    $subject = 'Проверка работы рассылки';
    // mail($email, 'sd', $mess, 'From:'.$from); 

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; \r\n"; 
    //$headers .= "From: $from\r\n";

    $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";

    @mail($email, $subject, $mess, $headers);
}
```

Отправляю сообщения вставляя в HTML шаблон с такой шапкой:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- So that mobile will display zoomed in -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- enable media queries for windows phone 8 -->
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> <!-- disable auto telephone linking in iOS -->
```

Если в шаблоне прописать слово, то нормально русские символы видны, а если беру с базы данных (там кодировка UTF-8), то все русские символы слетают на знаки вопроса "?????????....". Уже пробовал ставить в функции отправки сообщение кодировку windows-1251 и CP1251, нечего не помогло.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, для начала попробуй перед получением данных из бдтвыполнить запрос

```
 SET NAMES utf8
```

Если не поможет, тогда раздели задачу на две. Сначала выводи свой шаблон просто в браузер, а когда начнет нормально выводиться - тогда пробуй отправить письмом.

Comment: спасибо вам! теперь отображается нормально но на почту все равно бытые приходят...

Answer (score 0):

Вот на всякий случай глянь популярное расширенное решение по отправке писем.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer